# insertAdjacentElement not accepting document fragment

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to execute below snippet

```js
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
let divElement = document.createElement('div');
    divElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', frag);
```

I am getting the below error.

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentElement' on 'Element': parameter 2 is not of type 'Element'.

What is the restriction here? reference about error details would be much appreciated.
Please suggest an alternative to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fragments can be composed of *multiple* elements, not just single elements. In such a case, if the technique in your question worked, `insertAdjacentElement` would be inserting *multiple* elements, not just a single element. (It's not called `insertAdjacentElements`)

It just isn't allowed. Unlike `appendChild`, `insertAdjacentElement` can't take a fragment as an argument.

You could iterate through all children of the fragment and insert them `afterend`:

```js
// Create fragment, append elements
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'span1';
fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'span2';
fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'span3';


// First cast fragment.children from an HTMLCollection to an Array
// Since insertAdjacentElement will remove the element from fragment.children
// It will mutate on each loop causing issue
const childrenAsArray = Array.from(fragment.children);
// Iterate through fragment 
for (const element of childrenAsArray ) {
  divElement.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', element);
}
```

```html
<div id="divElement"></div>
```

Or you could call `insertAdjacentElement` directly instead of putting the elements into a fragment first.

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot for clean explanation and snippets. What about performance in both cases? which one do you recommend?

Comment: Unless you're inserting an unreasonably huge number of elements, any performance differences will be completely insignificant and not worth worrying about. I think the fragment only adds noise, I'd prefer to insert the created elements directly. You could also use `insertBefore` and select the *next* sibling, which can take a fragment as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

[createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) is never part of main dom.In dom tree `document fragment` is replaced by its child. Also it cannot inherit from [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) base class. So it is not a valid element too. The syntax of [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) is `targetElement.insertAdjacentElement(position, element)` where element need to be a valid one as described by the above link.

Hence this error